# Query SharePoint List From C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, .net

I am new to SharePoint and am wanting to query a SharePoint site and return data to a C# windows form.  This is my scenario I have a text box where a user can input a ICDN number, then press a button.  I want to then run a select statement against the SharePoint site and

```
Select firstname, lastname, address, city, state, zip from sharepointlist where ICDN = textbox1.Text;
```

And populate corresponding textboxes on the windows forms with the returned values like such

```
textboxfname = firstname;
textboxlname = lastname;
textboxcity = city;
textboxstate = state;
textboxzip = zip;
```

Of course this is rough pseudocode, but the question at hand is how to query a specific field name from your sharepoint site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code. Make sure you're using Microsoft.SharePoint namespace.

```
string siteUrl = "http://mysharepointsite";
string webUrl = "/accounting";
string listName = "Data List";

// Use the site
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    // Use the web
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webUrl))
    {
        // Get the list
        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
        // Create our query
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        // Set the query string
        query.Query = string.Concat(
            "<Where><Eq>",
                "<FieldRef Name='ICDN'/>",
                "<Value Type='Text'>",
                    textbox1.Text,
                "</Value>",
            "</Eq></Where>",
            "<OrderBy>",
                "<FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='TRUE' />",
            "</OrderBy>");
        // Select our fields
        query.ViewFields = string.Concat(
            "<FieldRef Name='firstname' />",
            "<FieldRef Name='lastname' />",
            "<FieldRef Name='address' />",
            "<FieldRef Name='city' />",
            "<FieldRef Name='state' />",
            "<FieldRef Name='zip' />");
        // Get only the data that we need.
        query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
        // Fetch items
        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
        // Get first item
        SPItem item = items[0];
        // Assign our values
        textboxfname = Convert.ToString(item["firstname"]);
        textboxlname = Convert.ToString(item["lastname"]);
        textboxcity = Convert.ToString(item["city"]);
        textboxstate = Convert.ToString(item["state"]);
        textboxzip = Convert.ToString(item["zip"]);
    }
}
```